# Compress a file with the form of run length encoding

Tags: c

I have a problem compressing a file with the [run length encoding form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding), and write the compressed form to another file. For example the text  **feedqqqqqqqh**  must be written  **1f2e1d7q1h** to the second file of the input. To make the compression a struct is used to store the current data:

```
typedef struct{
    char c;     //Current character
    int count; //counter of the current character
}run;
```

After that i created two files and counted the size of the file that needs to be compressed:

```
FILE *fd1 = fopen(argv[1],"r");
FILE *fd2 = fopen(argv[2],"w"); 

fseek(fd1,0,SEEK_END); 
long size = ftell(fd1); //counts the size of fd1
rewind(fd1);
```

Then i made the algorythm of the compression but it prints wrong number and also skips some letters:

```
run s1;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if (i == 0){   //initializes the counter and character in the 1st loop 
        s1.c = fgetc(fd1);
        s1.count = 1;
    }else{
        if(s1.c == fgetc(fd1)){
            s1.count++;
        }else{
            fprintf(fd2,"%d%c",s1.count,s1.c);
            s1.c = fgetc(fd1);
            s1.count = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**"feedqqqqqqqh" prints "1f1e7q" rather than "1f2e1d7q1h"**

I think the program skips the odd characters and misfunctions the rest of the execution, but i can understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your program skips the "odd" characters, because you do not preserve every character you read.

Look at this line:

```
 if(s1.c == fgetc(fd1))
```

If this condition is false, you read a character, but threw it away.
You did not save it anywhere, then in the `else` clause you try to read yet another character, and the first one is lost forever.

You must save the result of `fgetc` to a temporary variable, and use that in your condition:

```
char cur = fgetc(fd1);
if (s1.c == cur) {
    ...
} else {
    ... /* do not call fgetc here again! */
}
```

Comment: Thank you i will try it and tell you what happens